# Styled-Components loses styles after reload

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am rendering a template server side first and everything seems to work fine on initial load. However on development, once I change the styles of a styled component and reload, the component loses all of its styles. Oddly enough, if I change it back to the original styles, the styles will return and append them to the element. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'client/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'client-build'),
    filename: 'client.bundle.js',
    publicPath: path.join('testapp', 'static'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          babelrc: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.pcss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {hmr: true},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json script to watch client src as it's using webpack

```
"dev:client": "webpack --watch --mode=development --progress",
```

server.js

```
...

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  ctx.type = 'text/html';
  ctx.body = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div id='root'>
  ${renderToString(<App><div>This is render from the server-side template</div></App>)}
  </div></body><script src="/testapp/static/client.bundle.js"></script></html>`;
});
app.listen(port);
```

client/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {hydrate} from 'react-dom';

import {App} from './components';

hydrate(
  <App>
    <div>This is render from the client-side</div>
  </App>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

e.g. styled-component > App Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const PropTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

const App = ({children}) => (
  <Container>
    {children}
  </Container>
);

App.propTypes = PropTypes;
export default App;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 90%;
  background: yellow;
`;
```

Comment: Check if the class that has been generated has not been generated in two different places?